# Incorrect result in excel array formula from UDF if returned array has only one element

Tags: excel, vba, array-formulas, custom-functions-excel

This seems a simple issue, but i cannot get through on it.

In my UDF the result is a dynamic array which is spill on a range of cells. Excel is not 365, so i select an undefined number of cells and then check the result where the values are not #N/A, and "resize" the result on it.

The issue is that if the returned array's length is only one, than all the other cells in the selected cells get the same result as the one (first cell) with the returned value. Would need #N/A in all the other except the first cell. Definitely need error value in "over the range cells"

```vb
Function testoneresult(length As Integer)

ReDim a(length - 1)
For i = 0 To length - 1
  a(i) = Rnd()
Next i
testoneresult = a
End Function
```

**Result**

[image: insert image here]

I tried some tricks but not works

Dim a(length-1,0)     or

b=a(0)
testoneresult=b        or

dim a(length)
(in this case the second value is 0.)  or

a(length)=1/0
(all cells #VALUE (expected))

Is this a version dependent result, and is there a workaround to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Application.Caller` to determine what range your function is being applied to. `Application.Caller` is not necessarily going to be a range every time so it needs to be tested but other than that, it is very easy to manage your case:

```vb
Function testoneresult(ByVal length As Integer) As Variant
    Dim a As Variant
    If TypeName(Application.Caller) = "Range" Then
        ReDim a(1 To Application.Caller.Columns.Count)
        If length > Application.Caller.Columns.Count Then length = Application.Caller.Columns.Count
    Else
        ReDim a(1 To length)
    End If
    Dim i As Long
    For i = LBound(a) To length
      a(i) = Rnd()
    Next i
    For i = 1 + length To UBound(a)
        a(i) = CVErr(xlErrNA)
    Next i
    testoneresult = a
End Function
```

Note:
If you were to type the formula `=testoneresult(ROW())`, you will see that it does not work.
The reason for that is that `ROW()` returns a 1-column array when used in an array formula. To have a proper integer, you need to type e.g. `=testoneresult(MIN(ROW())`.

Alternatively, you could change your parameter to be `length as Variant`, detect whether it comes as an integer or as an array and, in case of the latter, return a 2-dimensional array with 1 row per items inside `length`.

Comment: Thanks, but i need the reverse of your answer i.e. doesn't matter howmany cells are selected i need that the return array fill the selection, and the overselected cells are filled with ERROR value. This works normally if the returned array is longer than one as in the first row of the example (the last cell is N/A). But doesn't work if only one element is in the returned array like in the second row of example. The required result 0,767112 N/A N/A N/A N/A N/A

Comment: This function returns exactly your required result. When calling `=testoneresult(1)` on 6 neighboring cells of the same row, it puts N/A on the rightmost 5. Have you even tested it before commenting?

Comment: Excuse if my question was not clear. The testoneresult is only to demonstrate the issue, i.e. the different behaviour of the array function. In live usage the returned array length cannot be modified, because of the possible further usage of it. Therefore commented that i need reverse usage (function result determines the length of the returned array). In this case if the formula is `=Counta(testoneresult(1))` gives false results depending on the selected target range.

Comment: No idea what this means... what is a *false result*? A wrong result? If yes, based on what criteria from your question (not from a comment) is the above function giving you a wrong result? Cannot help if you do not give all the elements...

Comment: Sorry. Try my code with =Counta(testoneresult(1)). The result is 1. This is the expected.

Comment: `COUNTA` only makes sense when applied to 1 cell (since it returns only 1 number), why would you want to apply it to several cells? and the result you expect is bound to be equal to the parameter. Lastly, there are easy workarounds to ignore errors. I am not going to edit my answer based on some unclear comments, especially after I asked you to edit your question to make this clearer for everyone (and this is the 2nd time I am asking now). **DO EDIT YOUR QUESTION WITH CLEAR DETAILS**.